# javax validation constraints annotations are ignoring during validation

Tags: java, validation

(It is used only in tests)
I have dependencies (there are no spring or DI container)

```
    testCompile("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")
    testCompile("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final")
    testCompile("org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0")
```

and I can validate my data class via

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
violations = validator.validate(myDto);
```

Where myDto is

```
@RestrictionsAreValid
public class MyDto {    
       @NotNull
       @Positive
       private Integer value;
}
```

Where

```
 @Target(TYPE_USE)
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = RestrictionsAreValidImpl.class)
    public @interface RestrictionsAreValid {    
        String message() default "";    
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};    
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }
```

Where

```
public class RestrictionsAreValidImpl implements ConstraintValidator<RestrictionsAreValid, MyDto> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyDto myDto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { 
     some code
    } 
}
```

in this validator all works perfect, but not any annotations `avax.validation.constraints.NotNull` or `javax.validation.constraints.Positive` on the field are working, they are simply ignored

Please any help. Resolved

I am so sorry, my real case were nested dtos in each other, so only high level class validated, but not nested.

```
@RestrictionsAreValid
public class MyDto {    

    @Valid //  this annotation solve problem, and so on deeper in stricture
    private Map<String, AnotherDto> map;
}
```

and it is `AnotherDto`  has annotated fields, that were not validated. When I added `@Valid` on `map` field it start work correct

Answer (score -1):

For classes annotations, I use this:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = RestrictionsAreValidImpl.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RestrictionsAreValid {

    /**
     * message for exceptional case.
     *
     * @return message
     */
    String message() default "";

    /**
     * Groups allow you to restrict the set of constraints applied during validation.
     *
     * @return arrays of group classes.
     */
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    /**
     * Payloads can be used by clients of the Bean Validation API to assign custom payload objects to a constraint.
     * This attribute is not used by the API itself.
     *
     * @return arrays of payload classes.
     */
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class RestrictionsAreValidImpl implements ConstraintValidator<RestrictionsAreValid, MyDto> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyDto myDto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { 
     some code
    } 
}
```

Than in DTO :

```
@RestrictionsAreValid
public class DTO{
}
```